# cron job not executing

Tags: cron

my backup script in crontab is not getting executed, the crond log shows nothing about executing the job.  I edited /etc/crontab, then restarted crond. nada.  what's wrong?

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly

#backup home dir w/ important scripts
00 02 * * * root /home/backup.sh
```

Comment: What OS? How do you know crond is running? Does it appear in ps output? Is `/home/backup.sh` the correct filename? What's in root's mailbox? What are run-parts? Always use absolute pathnames when invoking programs from cron. Does a cronjob like `/bin/date > /tmp/date.cron` work?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `00 02 * * * root /home/backup.sh` by this:
`00 02 * * * ./home/backup.sh`

Answer (score 0):

```
# run-parts
@hourly /etc/cron.hourly
@daily /etc/cron.daily
@weekly /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly /etc/cron.monthly

#backup
@midnight /home/$username/backup.sh
```

if you are running this cron as root then the home would be something like /root/scripts/backup.sh

```
string         meaning
------         -------
@reboot        Run once, at startup.
@yearly        Run once a year, "0 0 1 1 *".
@annually      (same as @yearly)
@monthly       Run once a month, "0 0 1 * *".
@weekly        Run once a week, "0 0 * * 0".
@daily         Run once a day, "0 0 * * *".
@midnight      (same as @daily)
@hourly        Run once an hour, "0 * * * *".
```